# create php artisan migrate but not create new table in database

Tags: laravel

firstly I create a migration and in cmd, I run php artisan migrate but it didn't create a new table. it's showing this message. Do you have any answer, Senior Developers! please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you share us the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel Documentation for Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#rolling-back-migrations)

If you want to run the migration without saving any data in database you can :

```
php artisan migrate:fresh

// Refresh the database and run all database seeds...
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Comment: Thanks Romain Seite. after I run -php artisam migrate and error show like- 'base table or view already exist:1050 table 'password_resets' already exits(SQL: create table 'password_resets' ('email' varchar(255) not null, 'token' varchar(255) not null

Comment: try the php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: I tried as you told and it show -'dropped all tables successfully' with migration

Comment: And if you check your database, did you have new table ?

Comment: oh! now not occur error and it is ok .thanks a lot Romain Seite

Comment: Youre welcom, i edit my answer to correspond with your demand

Comment: after running php artisan migrate:fresh -is now ok and see new tables on my database.